# How to recursively yield generator by overloading yield_value?

Tags: c++, generator, c++-coroutine

I've created a `generator` that will have an overload `operator*` in order to be converted into `std::ranges::subrange` and I also want to overload `yield_value` from `promise_type` that accepts a subrange type that will be yielded recursively.

Source Code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class [[nodiscard]] generator {
  public:
    using value_type = T;
    struct promise_type;
    using handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

  private:
    handle_type handle_ { nullptr };

    explicit generator(handle_type handle) : handle_(handle) {}

  public:
    struct promise_type {
      value_type value_;

      generator<value_type> get_return_object() {
        return generator{ handle_type::from_promise(*this) };
      }

      std::suspend_always initial_suspend() { return {}; }
            
      std::suspend_always final_suspend() { return {}; }
           
      void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }

      std::suspend_always yield_value(const value_type& value) noexcept {
        value_ = value;
        return {};
      }
            
      template <typename U>
      std::suspend_never await_transform(U&&) = delete;

      void return_void() {}
    };

    generator() noexcept = default;
    generator(const generator&) = delete;
    generator(generator&& other) noexcept
    : handle_(std::move(other.handle_)) {
      other.handle_ = nullptr;
    }

    ~generator() { if (handle_) handle_.destroy(); }

    generator& operator=(const generator&) = delete;

    generator& operator=(generator&& other) noexcept {
      handle_ = std::move(other.handle_);
      other.handle_ = nullptr;
      return *this;
    }

    void swap(generator& other) noexcept {
      using std::swap;
      swap(handle_, other.handle_);
    }

    class iterator {
      private:
        handle_type handle_;
        friend generator;

        explicit iterator(handle_type handle) noexcept
        : handle_(handle) {}

      public:
        using value_type = std::remove_cvref_t<T>;
        using reference  = value_type&;
        using const_reference = const value_type&;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using const_pointer = const value_type*;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

        iterator() noexcept = default;

        friend bool operator==(const iterator& iter, std::default_sentinel_t) noexcept {
          return iter.handle_.done();
        }

        friend bool operator==(std::default_sentinel_t s, const iterator& iter) noexcept {
          return (iter == s);
        }

        iterator& operator++() {
          if (handle_.done()) handle_.promise().unhandled_exception();
          handle_.resume();
          return *this;          
        }

        iterator operator++(int) {
          auto temp = *this;
          ++*this;
          return temp;
        }

        reference operator*() noexcept {
          return handle_.promise().value_;
        }

        pointer operator->() noexcept {
          return std::addressof(operator*());
        }

    };

    iterator begin() noexcept {
      if (handle_) {
        handle_.resume();
        if (handle_.done())
          handle_.promise().unhandled_exception();
      }
      return iterator{handle_};
    }

    std::default_sentinel_t end() noexcept {
        return std::default_sentinel;
    }
};
```

Example:

```cpp
auto generate_0(int n) -> generator<int> {
  while (n != 0)
    co_yield n--;
}

auto generate_1() -> generator<int> {
  for (const auto& elem : generate_0(10)) {
    co_yield elem;
  }
}
```

`generate_1` will work obviously but I want have the same output like the `generate_1` that each element is `co_yield`-ed directly inside the `yield_value`:

```cpp
auto generate_1() -> generator<int> {
  co_yield* generate_0(10);
}
```

Such that:
In class `generator`:

```cpp
auto operator*() {
      return std::ranges::subrange(begin(), end());
}
```

In nested class `generator<...>::promise_type`:

```cpp
template <typename U>
std::suspend_always yield_value(const std::ranges::subrange<U, std::default_sentinel_t>& r) noexcept {
  /** ... **/
  return {};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: bugs/odd bits on your end.

- I don't think it's worth it trying to support old-style iterators. It *doesn't* make sense to default-construct `generator<T>::iterator`, and the new-style iterator concepts do not require it. You can tear out a lot of junk from `iterator`.

  - Also, `==` is magical. If `x == y` doesn't find a matching `operator==` but `y == x` does, then `x == y` is automatically rewritten to `y == x`. You don't need to provide both `operator==`s.
- The `promise_type` does not need to hold `T` by value. An odd thing about yielding things from coroutines is that if you make `yield_value` take by-reference, you can get a reference to something that lives in the coroutine state. But the coroutine state is preserved until you resume it! So `promise_type` can instead hold `T const*`. Now you no longer require annoying things like copyability and default-constructibility from `T`.
- It appears to be unnatural for a `generator` to initially suspend. Currently, if you do `g.begin(); g.begin();`, you will advance the generator even though you've incremented no iterator. If you make `g.begin()` *not* resume the coroutine and remove the initital suspension, everything just works. Alternatively, you could make `generator` track whether it has started the coroutine and only advance it to the first yield on `begin()`, but that's complicated.
- While calling `std::terminate()` on every operation that's normally UB may be nice, it's also noisy and I'm just not going to include it in this answer. Also, *please* don't call it via `unhandled_exception`. That's just confusing: `unhandled_exception` has one very specific purpose and meaning and you are just not respecting that.
- `generator<T>::operator=(generator&&)` leaks `*this`'s coroutine state! Also, your `swap` is nonstandard because it is not a free 2-arg function. We can fix these by making `operator=` do what `swap` did and then getting rid of `swap` because `std::swap` works.

From a design/theory standpoint, I think it makes more sense to implement this syntax instead.

```
auto generate_1() -> generator<int> {
  co_await generate_0(10);
}
```

A `generator` can temporarily give up control to another and may resume running after it `await`s for the inner `generator` to run out. Implementing something to yield from a range can be easily implemented atop this by making a generator wrapping the range. This also lines up with the syntax in other languages like Haskell.

Now, coroutines have no stack. That means that as soon as we cross a function call boundary away from a coroutine like `generate_1`, it is not possible to suspend/resume that function via the coroutine state associated with the caller. So we have to implement our own stack, where we extend our coroutine state (`promise_type`) with the ability to record that it is currently pulling from another coroutine instead of having its own value. (Please note this would also apply to yielding from a range: whatever function is called to receive the range from `generator_1` will not be able to control `generator_1`'s coroutine.) We do this by making `promise_type` hold a

```
std::variant<T const*, std::subrange<iterator, std::default_sentinel_t>> value;
```

Note that `promise_type` does not *own* the `generator` represented by the `subrange`. Most of the time (as it is in `generator_1`) the same trick as `yield_value` applies: the `generator` which owns the sub-coroutine's state lives inside the caller coroutine's stack.

(This is also a point against directly implementing `co_yield` from a range: we need to fix the type of whatever is going into `promise_type`. From an API standpoint, it's understandable for `co_await` inside a `generator<T>` to accept `generator<T>`s. But if we implemented `co_yield` we'd only be able to directly handle one specific kind of range—a `subrange` wrapping a `generator`. That'd be weird. And to do otherwise we'd need to implement type-erasure; but the most obvious way to type-erase a range in this context is to make a `generator`. So we're back to a `generator` `await`ing on another as being the more fundamental operation.)

The stack of running `generator`s is now a linked-list threaded through their `promise_type`s. Everything else just writes itself.

```
struct suspend_maybe { // just a general-purpose helper
    bool ready;
    explicit suspend_maybe(bool ready) : ready(ready) { }
    bool await_ready() const noexcept { return ready; }
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<>) const noexcept { }
    void await_resume() const noexcept { }
};

template<typename T>
class [[nodiscard]] generator {
public:
    struct iterator;
    struct promise_type;
    using handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
    using range_type = std::ranges::subrange<iterator, std::default_sentinel_t>;

private:
    handle_type handle;

    explicit generator(handle_type handle) : handle(std::move(handle)) { }
public:
    class iterator {
    private:
        handle_type handle;
        friend generator;

        explicit iterator(handle_type handle) noexcept : handle(handle) { }
    public:
        // less clutter
        using iterator_concept = std::input_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = std::remove_cvref_t<T>;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

        // just need the one
        bool operator==(std::default_sentinel_t) const noexcept {
            return handle.done();
        }
        // need to muck around inside promise_type for this, so the definition is pulled out to break the cycle
        inline iterator &operator++();
        void operator++(int) { operator++(); }
        // again, need to see into promise_type
        inline T const *operator->() const noexcept;
        T const &operator*() const noexcept {
          return *operator->();
        }
    };
    iterator begin() noexcept {
        return iterator{handle};
    }
    std::default_sentinel_t end() const noexcept {
        return std::default_sentinel;
    }

    struct promise_type {
        // invariant: whenever the coroutine is non-finally suspended, this is nonempty
        // either the T const* is nonnull or the range_type is nonempty
        // note that neither of these own the data (T object or generator)
        // the coroutine's suspended state is often the actual owner
        std::variant<T const*, range_type> value = nullptr;

        generator get_return_object() {
            return generator(handle_type::from_promise(*this));
        }
        // initially suspending does not play nice with the conventional asymmetry between begin() and end()
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }
        std::suspend_always yield_value(T const &x) noexcept {
            value = std::addressof(x);
            return {};
        }
        suspend_maybe await_transform(generator &&source) noexcept {
            range_type range(source);
            value = range;
            return suspend_maybe(range.empty());
        }
        void return_void() { }
    };

    generator(generator const&) = delete;
    generator(generator &&other) noexcept : handle(std::move(other.handle)) {
        other.handle = nullptr;
    }
    ~generator() { if(handle) handle.destroy(); }
    generator& operator=(generator const&) = delete;
    generator& operator=(generator &&other) noexcept {
        // idiom: implementing assignment by swapping means the impending destruction/reuse of other implicitly handles cleanup of the resource being thrown away (which originated in *this)
        std::swap(handle, other.handle);
        return *this;
    }
};

// these are both recursive because I can't be bothered otherwise
// feel free to change that if it actually bites
template<typename T>
inline auto generator<T>::iterator::operator++() -> iterator& {
    struct visitor {
        handle_type handle;
        void operator()(T const*) { handle(); }
        void operator()(range_type &r) {
            if(r.advance(1).empty()) handle();
        }
    };
    std::visit(visitor(handle), handle.promise().value);
    return *this;
}
template<typename T>
inline auto generator<T>::iterator::operator->() const noexcept -> T const* {
    struct visitor {
        T const *operator()(T const *x) { return x; }
        T const *operator()(range_type &r) {
            return r.begin().operator->();
        }
    };
    return std::visit(visitor(), handle.promise().value);
}
```

Nothing appears to be on fire.

```
static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<generator<unsigned>>); // you really don't need all that junk in iterator!
generator<unsigned> generate_0(unsigned n) {
    while(n != 0) co_yield n--;
}
generator<unsigned> generate_1(unsigned n) {
    co_yield 0;
    co_await generate_0(n);
    co_yield 0;
}
int main() {
    auto g = generate_1(5);
    for(auto i : g) std::cout << i << "\n"; // 0 5 4 3 2 1 0 as expected
    // even better, asan is happy!
}
```

If you want to yield values from an arbitrary range, I would just implement this type-eraser.

```
auto generate_all(std::ranges::input_range auto &&r) -> generator<std::ranges::range_value_t<decltype(r)>> {
    for(auto &&x : std::forward<decltype(r)>(r)) co_yield std::forward<decltype(x)>(x);
}
```

So you get e.g.

```
generator<unsigned> generate_1(unsigned n) {
    co_await generate_all(std::array{41u, 42u, 43u});
    co_await generate_0(n);
    co_yield 0;
}
```